# When to initialize collection properties in Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relational-database

I am confused about initializing navigation properties which are of a collection type. In examples I see on web, the properties are always explicitly initialized in class constructor, however in my project I have two sets of such properties and one work without such initialization, one not:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.InverseProperty("Requested")]
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Friendship> RequestedFriendships { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.InverseProperty("Received")]
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Message> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<User> Received { get; set; }
} 

public class Friendship
{
    public int FriendshipId { get; set; }
    public int RequestedUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Requested { get; set; }
}
```

The following works:

```
db.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == userId).RequestedFriendships.Add(new B.Models.Friendship
{
    RequestedUserId = userId,
});
```

Also this:

```
B.Models.Message message = db.Messages.Add(new B.Models.Message
{
    Message = text
});
db.SaveChanges();
```

However following the above the below fails:

```
message.Received.Add(db.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == userId));
```

Since `message.Received` is `null` above. What is the difference here from the first successful one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference i see here is that your `User` instance is loaded from the database, which means that EF sets your properties, including navigation collections (with empty collections if no relationship is found for this `User`). However, your `Message` instance is created in your code (`new B.Models.Message { Message = text }`), your navigation collection is not initialized so you get an exception when you try to add an item in it.

I suggest you always initialize such navigation collections in your constructors when dealing with entities.